# Add an arrow to a dropdown to indicate it's a hover item

Tags: css

I'm implementing this dropdown menu: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

I want to add an arrow to the dropdown to indicate it's a hover item. I tried using content. Here is the code

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  content: ' ▾';
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added `content: ' ▾'` to the `.dropbtn` class but it did not work.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Yes, I do understand what you said. If the OP had given a basic code, what OP did, it would have been better. I know you aren't blaming anyone. Thanks for the insight. I would also really agree with you that Stack Overflow, now-a-days gets too much spam posted by newbies and as well as newbies are pelted with stones. Just to make the content, the best. Sorry if I have hurt you or your feelings in any way, but yes, I do agree with what you said. The way to use the `content` is available in a simple Google Search. People are asking questions without efforts.

Comment: @uraza See my above comment. Plus, I have a few resources for you: [CSS Tricks - CSS Content](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/): *CSS has a property called `content`. It can only be used with the pseudo elements `:after` and `:before`. It is written like a pseudo selector (with the colon), but it's called a pseudo element because it's not actually selecting anything that exists on the page but adding something new to the page.*

Comment: @PraveenKumar I understand why you wanted to close it which was a mistake by my part but when I wrote the question I thought adding a link would be easier both for me and those who wanted to answer the question.

Comment: @uraza You are welcome. And you understood the point as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is, you need to use `content` in a different way. First of all, this is the result of following the website W3Schools, which contains misleading and outdated contents. Best example, your understanding from the website.

Taking the content from the awesome CSS Website [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/), it says:

> CSS has a property called `content`. It can only be used with the pseudo elements `:after` and `:before`. It is written like a pseudo selector (with the colon), but it's called a pseudo element because it's not actually selecting anything that exists on the page but adding something new to the page.

So you need to make use of the pseudo codes:

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.dropbtn:after {
  content: ' ▾';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 10px;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: Great answer. In my opinion it became a quality posts for newbies, who want to *add an arrow to the dropdown to indicate it's a hover item*, despite of the fact it was put on hold. :P

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Saw your edit. Great, it is nice that you are helping to make Stack Overflow better. :D